# Giving Usernames to users with Firebase & Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a new to programming, and right now I want to give my users a username and then store it in the firebase real time database. However, every time I run my code it comes up with:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

I have checked all of my @IB buttons etc for clashes but there is nothing that I can find. I think I have written code that may be out dated so I am hoping someone can shed some light on my situation and help out!

I think there error is coming from here:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HandlerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!

    var user : AnyObject?
    var ref = DatabaseReference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func joinHaps(_ sender: Any) {

        ref.child("Usernames").childByAutoId().setValue(username)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"HomeScreenOne", sender: nil)
    }

    }
```

Comment: In which line you're getting error? also add crash log

Comment: I am receiving the error thread 1: signal sigabrt in my app delegate. Which from what I know could mean anywhere in my code could be an error?

Comment: and this is the crash log I think the error has come from. Thank you heaps for the help ! Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type UITextField at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: The username var is a textField and you cannot write a text field to Firebase. However, you *can* get the text that's *in* the text field and write that text (as a NSString) You need to get the string of that field with `username.text` before writing it to Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your crash log saying `'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type UITextField at`,

In this line your getting error, because `setValue` can't accept `UITextField` as input.

Change your code to :

```
@IBAction func joinHaps(_ sender: Any) {
    //username is UITextfield, you can fetch text from it using .text

    ref.child("Usernames").childByAutoId().setValue(username.text ?? "")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"HomeScreenOne", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! Exactly the answer I needed !!